# converting check_call statement to subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running into the below error while converting a check_call statement to subprocess.Popen,am messing up around "&&" I think ,can anyone help on how to fix it?

```
check_call("git fetch ssh://username@company.com:29418/platform/vendor/company-proprietary/radio %s && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD" % change_ref , shell=True)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'fetch', 'ssh://username@company.com:29418/platform/vendor/company-proprietary/radio', change_ref , '&& git' , 'cherry-pick', 'FETCH_HEAD'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Error:-

fatal: Invalid refspec '&& git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rc = Popen("cmd1 && cmd2", shell=True).wait()
if rc != 0:
   raise Error(rc)
```

Or

```
rc = Popen(["git", "fetch", "ssh://...", change_ref]).wait()
if rc != 0:
   raise Error("git fetch failed: %d" % rc)
rc = Popen("git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD".split()).wait()
if rc != 0:
   raise Error("git cherry-pick failed: %d" % rc)
```

To capture `stderr`:

```
proc_fetch = Popen(["git", "fetch", "ssh://...", change_ref], stderr=PIPE)
stderr = proc_fetch.communicate()[1]
if p.returncode == 0: # success
   p = Popen("git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD".split(), stderr=PIPE)
   stderr = p.communicate()[1]
   if p.returncode != 0: # cherry-pick failed
      # handle stderr here
      ...
else: # fetch failed
    # handle stderr here
    ...
```

Comment: @Sebastian - wonderful,you are right..Martijn code did not work...yours works right away..thanks a lot

Comment: @sebastian - one question actually..when the fetch or cherrypick fails,I dont want to print the stderr on the console or rather raise an error..i want to capture and parse the error and do some operation based on the error message..how can I change above without changing the existing functionality?

Comment: @user1934146: I've added `stderr` capturing

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is a shell feature. Run the commands separately:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'fetch', 'ssh://username@company.com:29418/platform/vendor/company-proprietary/radio', change_ref], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()  # Wait for completion, capture stderr

# Optional: test if there were no errors
if not proc.returncode:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['git' , 'cherry-pick', 'FETCH_HEAD'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
```

Comment: any chance we can club them together?

Comment: it is wrong. `Popen()` is async and doesn't wait for the `git fetch` to complete as the original command does.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I didn't get a chance to complete things; was called away. The `proc.communicate()` is missing here, hence the `# ...` in between.